# 12 month 13 week running average

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I have table like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(date     DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,incoming   INT NOT NULL
,closed   INT NOT NULL
,outstanding INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('2013-02-01'   ,1448       ,1309      ,14914),
('2013-03-01'   ,1458       ,1492      ,14880),
('2013-04-01'   ,1392       ,1439      ,14833),
('2013-05-01'   ,1367       ,1273      ,14927),
('2013-06-01'   ,1331       ,1240      ,15018),
('2013-07-01'   ,1410       ,1336      ,15092),
('2013-08-01'   ,1284       ,1418      ,14958),
('2013-09-01'   ,1210       ,1286      ,14882),
('2013-10-01'   ,1158       ,1067      ,14973),
('2013-11-01'   ,989        ,1018      ,14944),
('2013-12-01'   ,791        ,932       ,14803),
('2014-01-01'   ,637        ,956       ,14484);
```

How do I calculate 12 month 13 week running average form current date using mysql query ?

I want result like this

```
quarter   incoming  closed      outstanding
-------------------------------------
Q1        1416        1425          1460
Q2        1308        1345          1530
Q3         751         950          1412
Q4         825         945          1420
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Given your current data, what should your results be?  What does "12-month 13-week" mean - is the average over that total time period, do you want the data from a period of 13 weeks averaged in a moving 12-month window, or what?  When does a week start?  Attempts you've made to solve this problem will help us figure out what you need.  The data you've shown appears to be aggregated based on month, which is going to throw things off regardless.

Comment: Result should be mean of incoming,outstanding,closed which will be devided in to 4 outers.I need the data from a period of 13 weeks averaged in a moving 12-month window.week will starts form every monday.

Comment: So in the result set, incoming is AVG(incoming) for a given 13 week period? And closed is AVG(closed) for that period? But what's outstanding?

Comment: I've heard of a 12-month moving average, and I've heard of a 13-week moving average, but I've never heard of a 12-month, 13-week moving average.

Comment: yes.result set should be  AVG(incoming),AVG(closed),AVG(outstanding)

Comment: humm 12month=52 week divided/13 weeks so will get four quarter data

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your suggestions. I find out the answer .it maybe helpful for others.

select 'Q1' quter,AVG(incoming),AVG(outstanding),AVG(closed) from my_table where date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH) AND  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -9 MONTH)
UNION
select 'Q2',AVG(incoming),AVG(outstanding),AVG(closed) from my_table 
where date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -9 MONTH) AND  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH)
UNION
select 'Q3',AVG(incoming),AVG(outstanding),AVG(closed) from my_table
where date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH) AND  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH)
UNION
select 'Q4',AVG(incoming),AVG(outstanding),AVG(closed) from my_table
where date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND CURDATE()